# How to select two table's particular column data in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `course_purchase` another is `tbl_users`. In the `course_purchase` table I have `user_id` and similarly in the `tbl_users` I have users data. I need the data like from `tbl_users` only select `phone` and `name`. On the other side from `course_purchase` select all data's, I have already tried `INNER JOIN` but it's selecting all the data from both table.

Tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `course_purchase` INNER JOIN tbl_users ON course_purchase.user_id = tbl_users.user_id WHERE course_purchase.course_id = 47;
```

How can I get the data like this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please read the manual 'A select list consisting only of a single unqualified * can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables:'' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html it's better to select the columns you need in most cases

Comment: SELECT tu.phone, tu.name FROM course_purchase cp INNER JOIN tbl_users tu ON course_purchase.user_id = tbl_users.user_id WHERE course_purchase.course_id = 47;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9925191/rose) Gave the solution of this question, Thank you, I would like to modify the answer, He put at the last of the code full table name `ON course_purchase.user_id` there should  `ON cp.user_id` and so on.

The modified query is:

```
SELECT tu.phone, tu.name FROM course_purchase cp INNER JOIN tbl_users tu ON cp.user_id = tu.user_id WHERE cp.course_id = 47;
```